# Server-side Experiment with Google Analytics. Trouble with getting report

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have several block of html and want to know conversion of whole site depending on these blocks. There are a lot of pages with this blocks (/question/x/, /question/y/ etc) and I can't use standart A/B experiment. So I used [this manual](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/experiments) to test these blocks.

1. First of all I created experiment at the admin page of GA: 
   [image: Experiment settings screenshot] As you see, urls are not real because I don't have the one page with experiment.
2. I added this code to a page:

   `<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=XXXXXXXXXX_XXXX"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
       _udn = "mydomain.ru";
       cxApi.setDomainName("mydomain.ru");
       cxApi.setChosenVariation(1, // Generated on backend
           "XXXXXXXXXX_XXXX"
       );
       _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "question_page_split_test", "var_1"]);
   </script>`

Network log in browser shows that some data goes to google: http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.5.7dc&utms=3&utmn=965640....g%240%3A4%3B&utmu=qh~ Here all the parameters that it sends:

```
utmwv:5.5.7dc
utms:3
utmn:9631231230
utmhn:mydomain.ru
utme:8(question_page_split_test)9(question_page_test_var_1)11(1)
utmcs:UTF-8
utmsr:1920x1080
utmvp:1905x514
utmsc:24-bit
utmul:en-us
utmje:1
utmfl:14.0 r0
utmdt:Page title here
utmhid:120312275
utmr:-
utmp:/question/312/
utmht:141012312313684
utmac:UA-27XXXX33-1
utmxkey:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXX
utmcc:__utma=132303439.968256310.1410876532.1410876532.1410878876.2;+__utmz=132303439.1410876532.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);+__utmx=132303439.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXX$0:4;
utmu:qh~
```

After several hours of running there is no data in report. Whet is the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to wait for several hours.